# CSS-Shapes: Auto-adapt size of a triangle to the text inside it

Tags: javascript, css, css-shapes

I am trying to fit text into a triangle with fixed incline using CSS Shapes and need the triangle to adapt to text length. If the triangle's container isn't wide enough, it should turn into a trapezoid. Also, it should not be larger than needed either. However, I am constantly producing overflow or unnecessary whitespace.

[desired result with short text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eobWc.png)
[desired result with long text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOPfj.png)

As recommended elsewhere, I am using floated elements to push the text into shape. Also, I set `display:grid` on the parent so that I access the triangle's height to place the 2nd cutout at the bottom. For the code here, I replaced the text with boxes to make gaps / overflow more apparent. Also, there's no `clip-path` applied yet.

---

First try used a single Float:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle">
    <div class="cutter"></div>
    <div class="content">      
      <span class="item"></span><span class="item"></span>[...]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
html{
  --width: 40em;
  --incline: 0.2;
}
.container{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: var(--width);
  display:grid;
}
.triangle{

}
.cutter{
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0f08;
  shape-outside: var(--shape);
  clip-path: var(--shape);
  --shape: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%,
    100% calc(100% - var(--incline) * var(--width)),
    100% calc(var(--incline) * var(--width)));
}

.item{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: beige;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

CodePen: [short content](https://codepen.io/_xlf/pen/arLNvj); [long content](https://codepen.io/_xlf/pen/EzwPJE)

This version reliably produces overflow, probably because when element / grid cell height is determined, the 100% height of the float is assumed to be zero.

---

Thus, in the second version, I split the cutter in three parts: The top and bottom triangle cutouts and a middle one to push the triangles apart.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle">
    <div class="top cutter"></div>
    <div class="middle cutter"></div>
    <div class="bottom cutter"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <span class="item"></span><span class="item"></span>[...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
html{
  --width: 40em;
  --incline: 0.2;
}
.container{/*same as above*/}
.cutter{
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}
.cutter.top{
  height: calc(var(--incline)*var(--width));
  shape-outside:polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path:polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  background-color: #0f08;
}
.cutter.middle{
  height: calc(100% - 2 * var(--incline) * var(--width));
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  background-color: #0ff4;
}
.cutter.bottom{
  height: calc(var(--incline) * var(--width));
  background-color: #00f8;
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
.item{/*same as above*/}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/_xlf/pen/Bewjmg)

Here, the spacer appears to be ignored during height determination, thus in that phase the bottom triangle intersects too early, i.e. with text, the wrong paragraph. In my tests, this tends to produce excess whitespace, however, if e.g. during height determination the bottom triangle ends up in the gap between two paragraphs, overflow would occur.

Also, this approach doesn't allow the cutters to intersect, thus forcing a minimum size.

---

As I fear that the only safe CSS-only solution is cutting only the top, I tried some JavaScript: The naive version of incrementing/decrementing the triangles' height until hitting the edge between overflow and no overflow works, but is way to heavy on browser performance (i.e. the "This tab is slowing down your browser" message appeared). Setting the triangles `style.height` to its `scrollHeight`, however produces excess whitespace, especially if before the last box/word only needed one more pixel to fit.

Any tips on what I should try with CSS?
Or some suggestions on a more intelligent JS algorithm?

Btw, I'm fine with the solution only working in the most recent versions of Chrome and Firefox.